# Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile throws runtime exception

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

We are getting the following exception when Importing the AzurePublishSettingsFile:

PS C:\Users\xxx> Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "C:\xyz\azure.publishsettings"
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile : Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "C:\xyz\azure.publishsettings"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Subscription.ImportAzurePublishSettingsCommand

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: Can you check if the file is not corrupted? It should be an XML file. I have seen this case once on MSDN forums where this file was corrupted because JavaScript/Cookies were not enabled.

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I tried my first line for Azure:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile –PublishSettingsFile "C:\azure\1.publishsettings"
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile : Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile –PublishSettingsFile "C:\ubuntu\azure\1.publishs ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.ImportAzurePublishSettingsCommand
```

Turned out I had the wrong filename.

I think

> "Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile : Exception of type
>   'System.Exception' was thrown. At line:1 char:1"

could means the cmdlet didn't find the setting file ( this is the case for me).

If I run

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile –PublishSettingsFile "C:\notexist.publishsettings"
```

It shows the same error.

Have to say this is a very unclear error message.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: I just want the op know that if he put the wrong publishsettingsfile filename, he will get exact same error. not sure why this is not a answer.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem if I load the Azure module into a 64 bit version of Powershell. If I stick with the 32 bit version, the problem disappears. Is it possible that is the problem on your end?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I removed the spaces in the filename and worked fine :D

Answer (score -1):

Try to run the Power Shell as administrator, it resolved similar error for me